# itextpdf : set down image in paragraph

Tags: itext, itextpdf

Is it possible to set down an image into paragraph, something like that :

```
image.setBotom(-2)
```

??

I have the following code and my image is on the same position that "My text" and "abcd", and I want set down for 2px.

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C://myPDF.pdf"));
document.open ();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
Image image = Image.getInstance("C://myJPG.JPG");
Chunk ch = new Chunk(image, 0, 0, true);
p.add("My text");
p.add(ch);
p.add(new Chunk(" abcd "));
document.add(p);
document.close();
```

Comment: I explained in a previous answer that the Chunk constructor can be used to offset the image horizontally or vertically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32906567/1520650

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Itextpdf : set image in middle of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903402/itextpdf-set-image-in-middle-of-text)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it :

```
float offsetY = -4;
Chunk ch = new Chunk(image1, 0, offsetY, true);
```